# Efficient multiprocess querying of XML data in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, multiprocessing, lxml

I'm working on a Python 3 test script that compares data in two XML files (500+ MB on disk). The script reads the files into etree objects using LXML, then performs numerous pairs of xpath queries on the two files, comparing values returned by the queries.

Profiling indicates that the script spends most of its time performing xpath queries.

I've been experimenting with multiprocessing to distribute the work across multiple cores. The issue has been getting the sub-processes access to the etree objects:

```
gold = etree.parse(gold_file.as_posix())
audit = etree.parse(audit_file.as_posix())
```

I have the comparisons to perform on the two files in a list called `events`. Each element of this list is transformed into an xpath query to run on the two etree objects by `compare_func()` like so:

```
events = ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
res = pool.map(compare_func, events)
```

Presently I'm putting `gold` and `audit` in global memory. `compare_func()` uses the passed-in entry `event` from `events` to generate xpath queries against `gold` and `audit` to retrieve data and perform some comparisons:

```
def compare_func(event):
    global gold
    global audit
    query = ... transformation of event ...
    g_res = gold.xpath(query)
    a_res = audit.xapth(query)
    ... comparisons between g_res and a_res ...
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to put the etree objects in shared memory and pass references to `compare_func()` using `pool.starmap()` instead of `pool.map()`.

At no time are `gold` and `audit` altered.

Comment: Please explain `event` more detailed.

Comment: I updated the question with a better description of `event`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Profiling indicates that the script spends most of its time performing xpath queries.

Are you aware of the fact, that every `process` use his own copy of `gold/audit`.
There is no benefit to use `shared memory`.

I see it more efficient to use `xml parser` instead of multiple `xpath queries`. The difference is `xml parser` read your `xml` **one time**. But it's hard to tell as I don't know your `xml` Data and don't know if all or only some `xml nodes` have to be compared.

Comment: My understanding is that global data is copy-on-write for process creation on Linux. That is, the sub-process will access the parent's global memory locations until the it tries to write to those locations, at which point the impacted data is copied and updated. I'll look at xml parser for doing this.